# Understanding TFS Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Since yesterday I am using the TFS of Visual Studio.
I have a webserver where I installed the TFS server with SQL Server 2012 express.

Everything is working perfectly but I do have 1 question.

I have created a workspace on my laptop which is then linked to a team project on TFS.

What do I do if my laptop crashes? Are my files of my workspace copied to the TFS server when you do a sign in in Visual studio? 
Or do I need to use SVN repository like Tortoise to copy my projectfiles aside the TFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workspace is a local working copy of the code. TFS will act as a code repository in the same way as SVN does.

you should be able to view the code that is checked in to TFS by using the source control viewer.

the basic process is

- Create files in your local workspace
- When you are happy commit them to TFS by using the check-in command
- you can the edit / delete / add items to source control either by using the source control window, or the command line implementations.

you can find more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301771(v=vs.110).aspx#AddSource

Comment: ok and if my laptop crashes I can just setup my visual studio make a connection to the TFS and download a local copy of the projects again as last checked in on my TFS server?